# Not able to pass JSON object from Rest Client to MVC4 controller C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling the Controller action from Postman RestClient and passing the object but I am receiving values as 0.

Request URL : `http://localhost:27266/ImageProcessing/CreateThumbnail`

POST data :

```
{
"data":{
    "Width":140
    "Height":140
    }
}
```

to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult CreateThumbnail(InputDataModel data )
{
  return Json(new { Height = "0"});
}
```

where InputDataModel is

```
public class InputDataModel 
{
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving Width and Height as 0.

Am I missing anything.?

Comment: try just this part `{    "Width":140    "Height":140    }`.

Comment: You say you're receiving a null object, then you say Height and Width are 0.  Which one is it?

Comment: @BigDaddy : I corrected that, since int is non nullable so I am getting 0.

Comment: I think @JSantosh's reply may the answer and why aren't you using the passed-in object?

Comment: @JSantosh this also did not work.

Comment: @BigDaddy - I am using the passed in object, for the questions sake I cleared the inside code. My problem is to receive the data, not what to do with the data.

Comment: If you actually followed @JSantosh's answer your code should be working. If not, then something you're not telling us is wrong.

Comment: you said `I am receiving Width and Height as 0. ` . Where did you find it (in visual studio or in rest client response )?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the mapper will trawl the whole object tree to map - it needs to be told where to look, for example:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public InputDataModel data { get; set; }
}

public class InputDataModel 
{
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can adjust the JSON to conform to the `InputDataModel`, so it should have two members named `Width` and `Height`... not nested inside the `data` property.

Comment: Can you share the actual POST request? Perhaps it is missing the appropriate content type to tell the server it is sending JSON?